# Access violation error SNMP

Tags: delphi, snmp, access-violation

I'm writing a simple SNMP application to get information from comtech modem CDM-570L
(system descryption, power level and symbol rate for example).

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.UITypes, Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, IdUDPBase, IdUDPClient, idSNMP;

type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
      Nhap: TGroupBox;
      Label1: TLabel;
      Label2: TLabel;
      ButtonEnter: TButton;
      Xuat: TGroupBox;
      PowerLevel: TLabel;
    PowerLevelValue: TEdit;
      SymbolRate: TLabel;
    SymbolRateValue: TEdit;
      ButtonSave: TButton;
      dBm: TLabel;
      sps: TLabel;
      DeviceName: TLabel;
    HostIP: TEdit;
    ComString: TEdit;
    procedure BtnEnterClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  SNMP: TidSNMP;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.BtnEnterClick(Sender: TObject);
var dn, OID: string; //dn = device name, I mean system descryption

begin
  if Trim(HostIP.Text) = '' then begin
    MessageDlg('Chưa nhập IP của thiết bị!', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    Exit;
    end;
  if Trim(ComString.Text) = '' then begin
    MessageDlg('Chưa nhập SNMP read community string', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    Exit;
    end;
  PowerLevelValue.Clear;
  SymbolRateValue.Clear;
  SNMP.Host:= HostIP.Text;
  SNMP.Community:= ComString.Text;
  SNMP.ReceiveTimeout:=1000;
  if SNMP.QuickSend('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0',SNMP.Community,SNMP.Host,dn)
  then DeviceName.Caption:=dn;
end;

end.
```

An error occurred:

> First chance exception at $005D39C9. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x005d39c9: read of address 0x00000000'. Process Project1.exe (8156)

[image]

~~ My first post here, thanks for reading ~~

edit: sorry, no "if then", I forgot to edit

```
SNMP.QuickSend('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0',SNMP.Community,SNMP.Host,dn);
DeviceName.Caption:=dn;
```

Comment: For future reference, please use the debugger to work out which line triggers an exception, and include that detail in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SNMP` global variable is declared but never assigned to. Therefore it is `nil`. Attempts to refer to it will lead to an access violation. You must instantiate the object before using it.

More broadly I wonder why you are using a global variable here. Generally speaking, global variables are best avoided.

Comment: Thanks, it works!
just add 
Snmp :=TIdSNMP.Create(nil));

Comment: Oh wait, I can edit your answer, this is freaking ridiculous!